# Button with custom ControlTemplate sometimes misses clicks

Tags: wpf, button, controltemplate

My `Button` with a custom `ControlTemplate` does not respond to every click. I have no idea why, since it is totally random if the click works or not.

ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="KreisPlus">
    <Path Data="M74,37.5 C74,57.658393 57.658393,74 37.5,74 C17.341607,74 1,57.658393 1,37.5 C1,17.341607
            17.341607,1 37.5,1 C57.658393,1 74,17.341607 74,37.5 z M32.113861,13.5 L43.386139,13.5 43.386139,
            32.613861 62.5,32.613861 62.5,43.886139 43.386139,43.886139 43.386139,63 32.113861,63 32.113861,
            43.886139 13,43.886139 13,32.613861 32.113861,32.613861 z"
            Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFD7D7D7" Width="20">
        <Path.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1F71D5" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.94" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF6499E0" Offset="0.78" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button Click="Button_Click" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=KreisPlus}" />
```

Comment: you are getting the click when you are clicking on the Path even if the Button is filled, is that your issue?

Comment: I just tested it. The click only fires if i **don't** click on the Path. Only the blue BackGround responds to the click.

Comment: Have you tried making the Path IsHitTestVisible="False"?

Answer (score 2):

just try this code sample and see is that what you expect?

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="KreisPlus" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="Transparent" >
        <Path Data="M74,37.5 C74,57.658393 57.658393,74 37.5,74 C17.341607,74 1,57.658393 1,37.5 C1,17.341607 17.341607,1 37.5,1 C57.658393,1 74,17.341607 74,37.5 z M32.113861,13.5 L43.386139,13.5 43.386139,32.613861 62.5,32.613861 62.5,43.886139 43.386139,43.886139 43.386139,63 32.113861,63 32.113861,43.886139 13,43.886139 13,32.613861 32.113861,32.613861 z"
              Height="20"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="#FFD7D7D7"

              Width="20">
            <Path.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F71D5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White"
                                  Offset="0.94" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6499E0"
                                  Offset="0.78" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Now the path is inside the Grid and so it can respond to the click. This will take the entire area and only the path in the center. So if you click on the button anywhere even outside path will execute the click. If you don't want this and you want the path should respond to the click just change horizontal and vertical alignment as center

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. But honestly I don't know why. Does it has to do with events bubbling up, what they didn't do before?

Comment: don't forget to set the background